# Replacing HTML post action with PHP

Tags: php, regex

Edit: Just to clarify, I only want to open a file and change some text.

I have a basic HTML page with a form, and I want to change the POST action programatically with PHP.

I have this PHP script which I got from another post:

```
<?php

    $file = file_get_contents($argv[1]);
    $startPoint='action="';
    $endPoint='"';
    $newText='phpfile.php';
    $newFile = fopen($argv[1], "w");
    fwrite(
        $newFile,
        preg_replace(
            '#('.preg_quote($startPoint).')(.*)('.preg_quote($endPoint).')#si',
            '$1'.$newText.'$3',
            $file
        )
    );
    fclose($newFile);
?>
```

..and this HTML file:

```
<html>

    <form method="POST" action="https://www.example.com/">

    <input type="text" name="email">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" name="button">

    </form>

</html>
```

this does replace example.com with phpfile.php, but removes other lines of the HTML. This is what I'm left with after running the PHP script:

```
<html>

    <form method="POST" action="phpfile.php">

    </form>

</html>
```

I haven't been programming in PHP for long and some help would be appreciated.

Comment: Probably the worst idea ever for a login form.. but i think you know that :p the trick is getting that code on the server in the first place.

Comment: You should really study more about PHP, rewriting the file to change after login or whatever authentication flow you trying to implement is plain bad.

Comment: Why do you need rewriting the URL in form?

Comment: @Gntem Just to clearify, I don't want to change the file after login. I want to open the HTML file and replace the action link with another one without deleting the inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## First of all

Bad idea on replacing strings in files. A good way to approach this is having a php file with a variable which you could programatically define as the action file to be posted at.

## Anyway

As that was not the question, I don't know what those `#` were supposed to mean, but in PCRE(php regex parser), here is the fixed code :

```
preg_replace(
    '/('.preg_quote($startPoint).')(.*)('.preg_quote($endPoint).')/i',
    '$1'.$newText.'$3',
    $file
)
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to fix the problem!